# Gromov: 2+2=4 and Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I was watching a talk by the mathematician Gromov, and was perplexed by some things he said:

1) that 2+2=4 is related to Archimedes cylinder-sphere theorem, and 2) that this is related to the collapse of the wave function in quantum mechanics. I think he was being slightly facetious, but at the same time I'm sure he was saying something very deep. Can anyone please elaborate on what he was saying? I've posted a link to the video below. The relevant part is from about 9:50-13:00.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2LTRE6sX2o

I also wasn't sure which tag(s) would be appropriate for this question, so I apologize for that in advance.

Comment: Over the next ten minutes or so he explains the link between addition and Pythagoras. I'm still watching to see how he ties in the wavefunction. I'm assuming you're still perplexed after watching the rest of the video?

Comment: Yeah, he mentions that the Pythagorean theorem provides "motivation" for "Hilbertian" Geometry and the unitary group, and that Archimede's theorem is a corollary of the Pythagorean theorem, but I don't recall seeing in the video, though I may have missed it, where exactly the wave function comes in. The way he spoke about it, I thought it may be something the audience was already aware of and didn't warrant explanation.

Comment: I got the impression that you could use Pythagoras to show that the surface area of a sphere maps 1:1 to the surface area of a cylindrical surface; and separately he shows that rather than "rotating" a real number 180 degrees on a number line to get its negative, you can rotate by a different angle to get a complex number and use Pythagoras on that number in some way. But I'm not much for geometry.

Comment: The issue of 2+2=4 seemed to be about sets, and he mentioned the cardinality (i.e. which way the axes go) while discussing how to group the elements of the set, and again referenced Pythagoras there. That's even farther beyond me than geometry.